# Setting alias for DynDNS domain

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, dyndns, ns-record, a-record

I've created DynDNS domain for testing my local sites, and i'm having trouble with pointing to root domain.

From my registrar (GoDaddy) I've created a CNAME for www to point my example.dyndns.com

so going to url www.example.com I'm reaching my site.

But if I'm going to example.com I'm reaching to the IP of the A record. I can't set the IP for the A record to be my IP because I have dynamic IP, and it changes constatly, and I can't point the A record to domain, only IP.

When trying to create CNAME record @ to point example.dyndns.com I'm getting error "A record of a different type exists for the hostname @, could not create CNAME"

The only record using the '@' host are NS record, which I can't delete, and when tried to set another NS record with @ point to example.dyndns.com, I've lost connection to my site :)

So what can I do to get example.com url reach my site?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of registering a domain with DynDNS if you're not going to use their dynamic DNS service? What you're trying to do is possible by moving your name servers to DynDNS.

Comment: So there is no way I could create root alias for my dyndns domain from my registrar?

Comment: I'm confused. If GoDaddy is the registrar and you're using GoDaddy name servers, what exactly are you using DynDNS for?

Comment: because I want to use my home pc as host for developing, and I have dynamic IP. I use DynDNS to track my IP and asign it to domain.

Comment: Exactly. DynDNS is where your name servers should be and is where you set up your DNS records. I don't understand what you're trying to do at GoDaddy.

Comment: well basically because my domain was already registred at godaddy, and dyndns wants another 30$ a year for using their nameservers